# Go gorm order by association count

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have a following data structure:

```
type Collection struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name            string
    CollectionItems []CollectionItem
}

type CollectionItem struct {
    CollectionID uint
    ItemID     uint
    Item
}
```

How can I query `collections` table ordering results by a number of `collection_item` associations i.e. collections with most items come first.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: @Зелёный well for starters I've tried to read documentation several times but it has no hints as to how to achieve that. I could create a counter field and use it for sort but I don't want to manually maintain it. It would be really nice to have something like like rails' counter_cache but alas.

Comment: This really has nothing to do with GORM. This is just a matter of forming the right SQL query. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such feature like [`rails counter cache`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to-counter-cache) in the gorm, but gorm has callbacks [`before*` & `after*`](http://gorm.io/docs/hooks.html) so it is easy to implement order by collection count feature.

For example:

```
// Updating data in same transaction
func (c *Collection) AfterUpdate(tx *gorm.DB) (err error) {
  tx.Model(&Collection{}).Where("id = ?", c.ID).Update("items_count", gorm.Expr("items_count + ?", 1))
  return
}
```